# Ttk on python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter

I just installed python 2.7 from the python website, and was surprised to find that ttk wasn't included. Did I make a mistake installing, or is ttk really not included in the standard release? Anyway, where can I get a copy of ttk to install in my python instalation.

Note: I also heard that the activestate release has ttk. Should I unistall and use that instead?

Comment: For posterity, the question used to say "tkk" which was the issue that @Zonedabone was having. A moderator has annoyingly corrected the spelling, which makes no sense given that a spelling error was the problem. If you have a similar problem but you're typing "ttk" as it now says, and not "tkk" like it originally said, look elsewhere for a solution. Thanks overzealous SO mods!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you mean "ttk" not "tkk"

The following should solve your problems if this is the case:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
```

for more about ttk and Tkinter in python2.7, reference:
http://docs.python.org/library/ttk.html

Comment: I think doing a global import is a bad idea. The code would be much more readable (IMHO) if you did `import Tkinter as tk ; tk.Button...`. The extra three characters you have to type is outweighed by the disambiguation it provides.

Comment: I find the change to be inconsequential and pedantic especially considering the above code snippet is directly from the linked Python docs.

Comment: Yes! That was my problem! I was using tkk instead, and I didn't know that it was a subset of Tkinter. All is well now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Try this with Python 2.7:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as ttk
```

It makes this example work, which wouldn't otherwise:

http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html

Comment: you should copy the example into your answer, and keep the link as reference.

Comment: The OP wants the ttk module for Tkinter, not just Tkinter imported under the ttk name

Comment: Downvoted, because @ChrisLieb is right, this is not doing what OP needs.

Answer (score -2):

Check out this similar question on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/184544/python-2-7-and-tkinter .

Summary is that it is disabled by default.

Comment: Is there a way for me to reenable tkk, or should I just switch over to activestate. I'm a bit wary about using a different python because I use py2exe and I want to continute using that.

Comment: The summary of the question you linked to seems to only show that the compile-time option is disabled by default. Are you saying that all distributions leave this disabled when making distributions?